# Error in MyApplication.java while building React Native Firebase app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to add Firebase to my existing React Native(0.63.4) app to add authentication. I have followed this [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/) for the initial setup.

Initially the gradle was built successfully. But after writing adding the authentication part it gives some error which I am unable to resolve.

The error looks like this:

[Override Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WPiS.jpg)

MyApplication.java code :

```
package com.example.cirl;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

 import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage;  //added manually

// import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;  //added manually
// import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;  //added manually

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.example.cirl.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList()
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    // @Override    
    // public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
    // return true;    
    // }  

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
        packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage());  // added manually
      //  packages.add(new MainReactPackage()); //added manually
      // packages.add(new RNFirebaseAuthPackage());  // added manually
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getJSBundleFile();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getBundleAssetName();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    }

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.example.cirl.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have imported `io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage;` and added `packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage());` to the getPackages() method as instructed in an error before this.

This was the previous error due to which I added those lines in MyApplication.java.

```
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
```

The current error says to override existing module, but I don't know how and where to add that method.

Comment: are use sure you added every dependency in your app/gradle file ?

Comment: implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_app") //Added manually    
This is the dependency which I have added given in the official documentation for manually linking android. But I am not supposed to add anything as my react native version supports autolinking. Then too, for the sake of checking if it works, I have added that dependency. But it doesn't. @AnkitPatel